# Group And Count. Simplify Code

Tags: entity-framework

I am counting the number of users created per day as follows:

```
IEnumerable<DateTime> dates = GetAllDatesForPeriod();

var rows = context.Users
  .Where(x => x.Created >= minDate && x.Created <= max.Date)
  .GroupBy(x => new { Year = x.Created.Year, Month = x.Created.Month, Day = x.Created.Day })
  .Select(x => new { Year = x.Key.Year, Month = x.Key.Month, Day = x.Key.Day, Count = x.Count() }).ToList()
  .Select(x => new DataModel { Date = new DateTime(x.Year, x.Month, x.Day), Users = x.Count }).ToList();

  rows.AddRange(dates.Where(x => !rows.Any(y => y.Date == x)).Select(x => new DataModel { Date = x, Users = 0 }));
```

The second Select is because I am not able to create a DateTime in the Ef query.

The AddRange is to fill the missing dates with a Count = 0.

This code is working. But is there a way to simplify this?

Thank You,
Miguel

Comment: THere is a number of DateTime related functions in EdmFunctions (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd486743.aspx)- have you tried these? You can use them in Linq queries - here is an example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12673792/datetime-adddays-entityframework

Comment: Hello, yes and I tried ... But I wasn't able to rally make it work. And sometimes is a little bit confusing. In this case what I really would like to avoid is to use two Selects. Wouldn't be possible to do in one step what the last select and add range do?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the main query:

```
var rows = context.Users
    .Where(x => x.Created >= minDate && x.Created <= max.Date)
    .GroupBy(u => EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(u.Created))
    .Select(g => new DataModel { Date = g.Key, Count = g.Count() }).ToList();
```

After that you can add missing dates as you already did.

Comment: I tried that before but then on my AddRange part I am not able to get rid of the error: "The best overloaded method match for 'System.Collections.Generic.List<AnonymousType#1>.AddRange(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<AnonymousType#1>)' has some invalid arguments